# How to automatically encrypt, sign, and forward root's email?

Tags: email, encryption, root, netbsd

I've recently been teaching myself about the BSDs and decided to pick up a NetBSD VPS. I don't always log in to this box every day (it's not actually doing anything that important), but I'd still like to monitor `root`'s mail. To that end, I started looking into how to forward `root`'s mail to an external account. I learned a little about the [`/etc/aliases`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?aliases+5+NetBSD-5.0) file, and it looks like I might be able to build up a pipeline to do this for me, but I'm treading into unfamiliar territory.

Is there a tutorial that covers this sort of thing? Is it even a good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19046/receive-pop-imap-email-and-then-forward-as-encrypted-to-gmail for a similar question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a normal user, e.g. juser, and add it to the `/etc/aliases` file on the right hand side of the root entry.

For normal forwarding of root-mail you would just create a `.forward` (which contains your external e-mail address) in the home directory of juser.

Regarding encryption you can use a MDA (mail delivery agent for that), e.g. `procmail` and for that. Instead of a `.forward` you have to create a `.procmailrc` file in the home directory of juser in that case.

Via `.procmailrc` you can pipe a message (header/body) through an external program, e.g. a simple script that basically contains some `gpg` command. And with the right rule at the end of the procmailrc, you can forward the (processed) message to your external e-mail address.

Comment: Procmail: see http://blog.fealdia.org/2008/06/14/encrypted-system-logs-to-gmail/

Answer (score 0):

The catch-all way to do this is to edit the `/etc/aliases` file:

```
root:   me@someplace.else.com,someone.else@different.place.com
```

Run `newaliases` and you should be good to go.

Note you probably have to doctor your MTA (sendmail, or whatever) so that the messages emitted don't get deleted as spam, but that's a larger issue.

Comment: And what about the encrypt and sign part of the question?